# Can i use nested BEGIN/END blocks in Triggers (mySQL)

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, nested, block

I would like to know why my code is not working. The ideia is to verify that when a idseq is added to a certain table, to see if that same idseq already exists in any other table.
The following code produces ERROR 1235 in mySQL:

```sql
delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_pagina
BEFORE INSERT ON pagina
    FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
            IF (EXISTS(
                SELECT R.idseq
                FROM registo R
                WHERE (NEW.idseq = R.idseq)
                ) )THEN
                    CALL Ilegal_Insert();
            END IF;
        END;

        BEGIN
            IF (EXISTS(
                SELECT T.idseq
                FROM tipo_registo T
                WHERE (NEW.idseq = T.idseq)
                )) THEN
                    CALL Ilegal_Insert();
            END IF;
        END;

        BEGIN
            IF (EXISTS(
                SELECT V.idseq
                FROM valor V
                WHERE (NEW.idseq = V.idseq)
                )) THEN
                    CALL Ilegal_Insert();
            END IF;
        END;

        BEGIN
            IF (EXISTS(
                SELECT C.idseq
                FROM campo C
                WHERE (NEW.idseq = C.idseq)
                )) THEN
                    CALL Ilegal_Insert();
            END IF;
        END;//

delimiter ;
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Try: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ac257/1) or [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90394/2).

Answer (score 0):

You need another, outermost `BEGIN ... END` block to enclose the ones you have above, like

```
delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_pagina
    BEFORE INSERT ON pagina
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN  -- Add a BEGIN here...
        BEGIN
            IF (EXISTS(
              ...
            END IF;
        END;
        BEGIN
          ...
        END;
    END; -- and an END here
    //
delimiter ;
```

This is because **CREATE TRIGGER** actually only allows the trigger body to contain a *single* statement, and **BEGIN ... END** is treated, along with its contents, as a *single* statement.

So yes, you can (and in this case *must*) use nested **BEGIN ... END** blocks in a trigger body.